# Arrange Data in buckets based on lower and upperlimit

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have run into a problem that is making me pull out all the hair out of my head and save my future visits to a salon. Ok here goes

**Summary**

I have an application that has an approver associated with it based on the upper and lower limit of the user. So if for a location I have to select an approver if the amount is $200 then it will check where this amount falls between the upper and the lower limit and select the user accordingly.

**Data and Desired Result**

[image: Approvers table]

and here is the result that I want

[image: Result]

**Problem Explanation**

For the resultset, I have buckets (1-500, 501-1000, 1001-2500, 2500-5000, 5001 and above) which hold the user that falls under the upper and lower limits. The problem is how data is stored. If you notice for locationID 1 the lower limit have contradictory values like there are 2 lower-limit with value 1 and different upper-limit. Likewise, locationID 2 have only one record. This makes it rather difficult to place users in their designated buckets. I am looking out for a solution to this.

**What I have tried**

I have tried to get the result by only using the upper limit and not considering the lower limits but it yields undesirable results. I can post the query here but knowingly it is wrong I don't think this is required. Also, I am well aware of the rules here, so please let me know if someone wants my **menacing** query

Please pretty Please save my hair (well what's left of them).

Comment: Is this a report or a query?

Comment: Could you post data as text? pictures cannot be copied to SSMS

Comment: why the downvotes?

Comment: @RossBush it's a query

Comment: @MikhailLobanov I'll post the data as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example**

```
Select [LocationID]
      ,[1-500]     = [1]
      ,[501-1000]  = [2]
      ,[1001-2500] = [3]
      ,[2501-5000] = [4]
      ,[5001 plus] = [5]
From (
        Select Top 1 with ties 
               [LocationID]
              ,[Col] = Tier
              ,[Value] = Username
         From YourTable A
         Join (values (1   ,500   ,1)
                     ,(501 ,1000  ,2)
                     ,(1001,2500  ,3)
                     ,(2501,5000  ,4)
                     ,(5001,999999,5)
              ) B (R1,R2,Tier) on B.R1 between A.LowerLimit and A.UpperLimit
         Order By Row_Number() over (Partition By LocationID,B.Tier Order By UpperLimit)
     ) A
 Pivot (max([Value]) For [Col] in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5]) ) p
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Never knew there was something like withTies. Thanks. Do you have a blog or something?

Comment: @ankitsuhail Happy it helped

Answer (score 0):

You want one record per location, so this means you'll want a group by on `LocationId` on your data.  Then you have to do aggregate functions on each column.  Something like:

```
select LocationID,
    min(case when 1 between LowerLimit and UpplerLimit and 500 between LowerLimit and UpperLimit then Username end) [1-500],
    min(case when 501 between LowerLimit and UpplerLimit and 1000 between LowerLimit and UpperLimit then Username end) [501-1000],
    ... etc.
from DataTable
group by LocationID
```

If there is any overlap in your ranges in the data, it will pick the smallest username alphabetically in the column (because of the `min` function).  If the range is not filled, the column will be `null`.